# Returning an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

Hi, I'm a newbie in C (and in programming) and I'm trying to make a function that returns dynamically allocated array. It looks like:

```
int *returnArray(void) 
{ 
  int i, *p[4]; 

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    if ((p[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(4-i))) == NULL)
      return NULL;  

  return &p[0][0];
}
```

And calling to this function:

```
int *ar;

if ((ar = returnArray()) == NULL) {
  /* ERROR */
  return 1;
}
```

But it doesn't work at all. After calling the function I wish to use *ar like a normal 2D array + unallocate the memory at the end of programme. Even if I've looked at similar topics I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you all for your help. I understand it much better now.

Comment: You're close. You need to allocate the first dimension, as well.

Comment: I haven't used C for a long time, but it seems that the *p is a local variable and it is can be used by other variables when exiting the function returnArray, maybe you need to allocate the p dynamically. Also using = and == on the same line make it less readable. I do not understand why are you allocating 4 - i bytes?

Comment: "But it doesn't work at all." - explain this with a code example that tests something.

Comment: Why this `(4-i)`? Because having done so, brings you in trouble when "*... use `*ar` like a normal 2D array.*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `returnArray`, variable `p` is a local variable, so you should not return its address.

You can return one of the values in it (for example - `p[2]`), but you will obviously lose all the others.

So instead of returning this array, pass it to the function and initialize the entries inside:

```
void initArray(int* p[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        p[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(SIZE-i));
}
```

Then, you can call this function and check if all allocations have completed successfully:

```
int i;
int* p[SIZE];
initArray(p);
for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    if (p[i] == NULL)
        break;
}
if (i < SIZE)
{
    //Error - not all allocations have completed successfully
}
else
{
    // Example #1
    scanf("%d",&p[3][0]);
    printf("%d",p[3][0]);
    // Example #2
    scanf("%d" , p[3]);
    printf("%d",*p[3]);
}
```

And of course, you will need to release the allocated memory at a later point in execution:

```
void freeArray(int* p[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (p[i])
            free(p[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, all allocations completed successfully - but if I want to fill the array in main() why I can't use this: scanf("%d", p[3]+0); ? Everything else is ok.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong before, now it works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You're close. What you are missing is that you need to allocate both dimensions, like this:

```
int** CreateTwoDimensionalArray(int rows, int cols)
{
   int row, prevrow;
   int** result = (int**) calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));
   if (result == NULL) {
     return NULL;
   }


   for (row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
     int* current_row = (int*) calloc(cols, sizeof(int));
     if (current_row == NULL) {
        for (prevrow = 0; prevrow < row; ++prevrow) {
           free(result[prevrow]);
        }
        free(result);
        return NULL;
     }
     result[row] = current_row;
   }  
   return result;
}

void FreeTwoDimensionalArray(int** array, int rows, int cols)
{
  int row;
  for (row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
     free(array[row]);
  }
  free(array);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it well. So, I have to use **result instead of *result[] ? And why is there row < row in for cycle?

Comment: @the_Imp, if you do: "int** a = CreateTwoDimensionalArray(n, m);", you can do "*r[index]".

Comment: @the_Imp as for "row < row"; that was a typo (which I've since fixed).  It should be "row < rows".

Comment: Thank you. I prefer **r too, but at school we had to use *r[] in test (but there weren't functions like this)... Btw, there's one more typo.

Comment: @the_Imp, also, since this is a two-dimensional array, I would recommend using "array[row_index][col_index]" to dereference an element in the two-dimensional array. It makes sense to use "**pointer" in the case where it is a pointer to just a single element.

Comment: I thought it should be for(row = 0; row < rows; ++row), but forgive me if I didn't understand you, my english isn't too good...

Comment: @the_Imp, thanks. I missed that one (I thought you were referring to something else).